# Porting from SQLite to PostgreSQL: What is according of datatype byte[] and DateTime in .NET 6 inside PostgreSQL 14.5 SQL DDL script?

Tags: .net, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

My context: I need creating an web-app use ASP.NET Core WebAPI .NET 6, Entity Framework Core 6, PostgreSQL 14.5 with JWT authentication/authorization. I mimics a sample at https://github.com/patrickgod/AuthenticationWebApi , then fork to me https://github.com/donhuvy/AuthenticationWebApi .

This source code use .NET 6 , SQLite , Entity Framework Core 6, HMACSHA512 :

```cs
namespace AuthenticationWebApi.Models

{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; } = new byte[32]; // <-- In don't know how to choose according datatype in PostgreSQL' DDL script.
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; } = new byte[32]; // <-- In don't know how to choose according datatype in PostgreSQL' DDL script.
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime TokenCreated { get; set; } // <-- In don't know how to choose according datatype in PostgreSQL' DDL script.
        public DateTime TokenExpires { get; set; } // <-- In don't know how to choose according datatype in PostgreSQL' DDL script.
        public string Role { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

source https://github.com/donhuvy/AuthenticationWebApi/blob/master/AuthenticationWebApi/Models/User.cs

I need migration to PostgreSQL 14.6 . My wrong SQL script is

```sql
CREATE TABLE public."my_user"
(
    id integer,
    username character varying(32),
    password_hash character varying(32), // <-- Incorrect mapping.
    password_salt character varying(32), // <-- Incorrect mapping.
    refresh_token character varying(32),
    token_created time with time zone, // <-- Incorrect mapping.
    token_expires time with time zone, // <-- Incorrect mapping.
    role text
);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."my_user"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I use table name `my_user` for avoiding duplicate with reserved keyword `user` in PostgreSQL database system.

Help me mapping correct datatype for SQL script inside PostgreSQL. I hope you understand my need (you can ask me for clarification).

Answer (score 0):

It is `bytea` and `timestamp without time zone`

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html

Comment: I still need more answer.

Answer (score 0):

As above, a .NET byte[] is mapped to a PostgreSQL [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html).

For DateTime, that depends: UTC timestamps are represented in PG by `timestamp with time zone`, whereas other timestamps (in some implicit local or unknown timezone) are represented by `timestamp without time zone`. Npgsql enforces this distinction in .NET by accepting only DateTime with Kind=UTC for `timestamp with time zone`, and only Kind with non-UTC for `timestamp without time zone`. So it's a question of what kind of timestamp data you're going to be saving there, and it affects the code you'll use to provide DateTime instances to Npgsql. See [the docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html#timestamps-and-timezones) and [this blog post](https://www.roji.org/postgresql-dotnet-timestamp-mapping) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

for `timestamp without time zone` you can use `timestamp` in your create expression.

for `imestamp with time zone` you can use `timestamptz` in your create expression.

see [docs write-mappings](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html#write-mappings)
and
see [PostgreSQL timestamp vs timestamptz](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/postgresql-timestamp-vs-timestamptz-616)