# What datatype of PostgreSQL 14.5 for DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, npgsql, nodatime

I am sorry, I revise totally the question.

I have entity

```cs
namespace AuthenticationWebApi.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; } = new byte[32];
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; } = new byte[32];
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime TokenCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime TokenExpires { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/patrickgod/AuthenticationWebApi/blob/master/AuthenticationWebApi/Models/User.cs . This sample use SQLite , I need use PostgreSQL 14.5

What datatype of PostgreSQL 14.5 for `DateTime` in .NET 6?

(I did not program C# often, mainly Java)

Comment: Are you sure you want `LocalTime` to represent the time of token expiration? The comparison would get really funky across date boundaries, and have you considered what happens across timezones? Wouldn't an `Instant` make more sense instead?

Comment: I very, very much doubt that you want to use `LocalTime` here. As Sweeper says, `Instant` makes a lot more sense for something like an expiry time. Judging by https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nodatime.html, that means you probably want "timestamp with time zone" in the database.

Comment: I am very sorry to Sweeper and Jon Skeet. I revise totally question.

Comment: So did you look at https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html, which is just above the doc that I referenced in my previous comment?

Comment: This question seems like a partial duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73676567/porting-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-what-is-according-of-datatype-byte-and-date. If you've decided to use DateTime instead of NodaTime, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73698611/640325). However, I strongly recommend using NodaTime, which is the better option and fully supported in Npgsql. You'd probably want to use Instant as @JonSkeet wrote above.